# GPRS data usage information

Tags: android

In my application, I need to get the information about gprs usage per request on internet. How can I get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look to Traffic Stats API:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html

Br